# Phanton Wallet - Get recent blockhash

Tags: phantom, react-native

I was using React native and the example provided by Phantom: https://github.com/phantom-labs/deep-link-demo-app/blob/20f19f2154e98699f0d5a6b28bc4bb3d5acbcefd/App.tsx

```
 const createTransferTransaction = async () => {
if (!phantomWalletPublicKey) {
  throw new Error('missing public key from user')
}
console.log('tcreate')
console.log(phantomWalletPublicKey)
let transaction = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: phantomWalletPublicKey,
    toPubkey: phantomWalletPublicKey,
    lamports: 100,
  }),
)
transaction.feePayer = phantomWalletPublicKey
const anyTransaction = transaction
anyTransaction.recentBlockhash = (
  await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
).blockhash
return transaction
}
```

however, when it comes to getting the recent hash of the transaction, a error appears:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: Network request failed]
at node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.browser.cjs.js:null in Connection#getLatestBlockhash
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in asyncGeneratorStep
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in _throw
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in flushedQueue
```

Please help to figure out the issue!

---

````
Getting recent blockhash

failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: Network request failed
at node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.browser.esm.js:null in Connection#getLatestBlockhash
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in asyncGeneratorStep
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in _throw
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in tryCallOne
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in flushedQueue

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(yield connection.getLatestBlockhash().catch(function (err) {]
at App.tsx:null in Promise$argument_0
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in asyncGeneratorStep
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in _next
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in tryCallOne
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in flushedQueue```
````

Comment: Hi! It looks like your network request for `connection.getLatestBlockhash` failed. This could be for a number of reasons. How often is this occurring for you? 

This code is for demo purposes, so we assumed that `connection.getLatestBlockhash` would succeed on most occasions. You could try wrapping the request in a try catch block.

Comment: It always occurs... never succeeds, I also wrapped it into a try-catch block, and the whole log is updated below as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have some issues with the RPC endpoint that you're using. Could you try switching to some other devnet endpoint and see if it works out?

e.g. `https://solana-devnet-rpc.allthatnode.com/`